# Match Arrays Value To Return All Matched Occurrences

Tags: javascript, arrays, matching

I'm in need of little help with records matching in two arrays with different length.

**Requirements**:

- Find same values between two arrays
- Return only that matched
- Push matched value back to the array where the values were found.

**Example:**

```
    var findFrom = ["Apple", "Mango", "Orange", "Mango", "Mango", "Apple"];

    var findTheseValues =  ["Apple", "Mango"];

    Returned Array = ["Apple", "Apple("Matched")", "Orange", "Mango", "Mango("Matched")", "Mango", "Mango(Matched)", "Apple("Matched")"];

    **// Push matched values next to the value that was matched in the FindFrom Array**
```

**I tried:**

```
var findFrom = ["Apple", "Mango", "Orange", "Banana", "Orange", "Orange","Orange"];
​
var findTheseValues = ["Orange", "Banana"];
​
for(let i = 0; i < findFrom.length; i++){
​
    if (findFrom[i] === findTheseValues[i] // toString() if required){
        console.log(findFrom[i]);
    }
}
```

If I just replace the 'i' in the if condition for find These Values with 0, it returns the matched values but I don't want it to match just one value - it should loop over both arrays.

Tried Find from ES 6 but it just returns one value that matched.

I'm happy to explain more if required & I appreciate the help! :)

Comment: You missed an `"apple"` at the end of the returned array, am I wrong?

Comment: your example won't run, x isn't defined anywhere. Also, you can't just loop over one of the arrays, you need to loop over findFrom and in that loop run over all the elements in findTheseValues.

Comment: To clarify, your intent is to create a new array (e.g. `Returned Array` in your example) based on `findFrom[]`, with the matched elements pushed into that array just to the right of the matched element?

Comment: Is the "Returned Array" in your post correct? I'm struggling to see the consistency there. Why does Mango appear 4 times, but Apple only 3? Why does Mango appear after Orange, even though the first match is before Orange? Why aren't the apples grouped together?

Comment: Do you really want the matched values to include the appended string "Matched"?

Comment: Sorry Guys - there was a type in the for loop and I've corrected it.

Comment: I mean  typo... sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works for me:

```js
  var findFrom = ["Apple", "Mango", "Orange", "Mango", "Mango", "Apple"];

  var findTheseValues =  ["Apple", "Mango"];

  var solution = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < findFrom.length; i++){
    solution.push(findFrom[i]);
    if (findTheseValues.indexOf(findFrom[i]) !== -1) {
      solution.push(findFrom[i] + ' (Matched)');
    }
  }

console.log(solution)
```

This loops through the array, tries to find the element at the index in "findthesevalues"- then pushes the "matched" string to the new array if we find a match

Comment: Thanks @chevybow -- I really like your solution and I might pick this one as an Answer - its really simple and is in Vanilla JS.

Comment: @Rehan Glad it was easy to understand!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map()` and `.includes()` methods:

```js
let findFrom = ["Apple", "Mango", "Orange", "Mango", "Mango", "Apple"],
    findTheseValues =  ["Apple", "Mango"];

let result = findFrom.map(s => s + (findTheseValues.includes(s) ? ` (${s})` : ''));

console.log(result);
```

**Docs:**

- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: *Push matched values next to the value that was matched in the FindFrom Array*

Comment: This is a nice compact solution, but it doesn't seem to yet yield the expected results. You are included the match in parens in the same string, rather than push the matched element to the right of the original value. But alas, since @rehan has not yet clarified, I'm not 100% certain on that.

Comment: Actually I do not think your update resolved the "issue". Maybe I am wrong but this is not in the form of `Returned Array`.

Comment: Thanks @MohammadUsman -- I like your solution but the problem is that I want a new Item added in the original array as 'Mango ("Matched")'  as shown in the Returned Array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Arrays map method which return a new set of array with matched text appended.

```
    var returnedArray = findFrom.map((ele)=> {
if(findTheseValues.indexOf(ele)!==-1){
   return [ele, ele+"(matcheed)"] // return a pair with appended matched
}else{
  return ele;
}
}).join().split(',') // to flatten array.
```

Comment: *Push matched values next to the value that was matched in the FindFrom Array*

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara yeah I missed that point. have updated code for it.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a decent solution that uses native Array methods instead of for-loops, which is always a better idea, imho.

Also, this will *also* allow you to look for the same value more than once, e.g. include a value more than once in your search.

```js
let findFrom = ["Apple", "Mango", "Orange", "Mango", "Mango", "Apple"];

// try either of the following
let findTheseValues =  ["Apple", "Mango"];
//let findTheseValues =  ["Apple", "Mango", "Mango"];

let results = [];
findFrom.forEach((i) => {
  const match = findTheseValues.filter((a) => i === a);
  const result = match.length > 0 ? match.concat(i) : i;
  results.push(i);
  if (match.length > 0) {
    match.forEach(m => results.push(m));
  };
});

console.log(results);
```

Comment: var findFrom = ["Apple", "Mango", "Orange", "Mango", "Mango", "Apple"];

var findTheseValues =  ["Apple", "Mango"];


var results = [];
findFrom.forEach((i) => {
  var match = findTheseValues.filter((a) => i === a);
  var result = match.length > 0 ? match.concat(i) : i;
  results.push(i);
  if (match.length > 0) {
    match.forEach(m => results.push(m + "(Matched)"));
  };
});

console.log(results);

Comment: Chad your Solution worked just like I wanted  - Not a requirement but would prefer a Vanilla JS solution on if possible.

I'll review few of the other posts before I pick the answer  - Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: Is there a reason for the plain-ole JS? I mean, these array methods are native at this point.

Comment: I agree with you Chad but the code I have written my application is raw so just found that convenient. But, I love your suggestion and will keep this approach in my for future.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```js
var findFrom = ["Apple", "Mango", "Orange", "Mango", "Mango", "Apple"];
var findTheseValues =  ["Apple", "Mango"];

var matches = findFrom.map((e, i)=>{
  return r = findTheseValues.includes(e) ? e + '(matched)' : e;
});

console.log(matches);
```

Comment: This solution has already been provided below. See @Mohammad Usman's answer.

Comment: gotcha! guess i was working on it when it got posted. Sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this answer because all other solutions proposed are based on linear searching over `findTheseValues` array, whereas the total computational complexity can be definitely reduced using a different data structure: I am talking about `Set`s or `Map`s. They are probably implemented using a hash table and as ECMAScript Standard says:

> must be implemented using either hash tables or other mechanisms that, on average, provide access times that are sublinear on the number of elements in the collection.

So, my solution is almost equal to the others, except for data structure used.

```
let findTheseValuesSet = new Set(findTheseValues);
let newArray = [];

findFrom.forEach(elem => {
    newArray.push(elem);
    if (findTheseValuesSet.has(elem))
        newArray.push(elem + '(Matched)');
});
```